# Are "It is rainy now" and "it is raining now" the same? Also what is the verb equivalent to the adjective "sunny"?

Tags: word-usage, difference, phrase-usage, phrase-choice

This is a little bit confusing.

> **[rainy](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/rainy?q=rainy)** (adj): having or bringing a lot of rain
>
> a rainy day
>
> the rainy season
>
> the rainiest place in Britain

---

Ad other dictionary

> **[rain‧y](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/rainy)** /ˈreɪni/ ●●● S3 adjective
>
> 1 a rainy period of time is one when it rains **a lot** SYN wet
>
> a cold rainy day in October
>
> I hate rainy weather.
>
> the rainy season

---

> **[rain](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/rain_2)** [intransitive] when it rains, water falls from the sky in drops
>
> Is it raining?
>
> It had been raining hard all night.
>
> It hardly rained at all last summer.
>
> It started to rain.

---

So, it seems like "**it is rainy now**" means "**it is raining a lot now**".

Ok, let say, we look out through the window, and the rain is falling from the sky, and the rain is light not too heavy or a lot. In this situation, do we say

"**It is rainy now**" or "it is raining now"?

And in the case that the rain is falling heavily or a lot outside. do we say

"**It is rainy now**" or "it is raining a lot now"?

Also, we have the adjective "**sunny**" but we have no verb equivalent to it.

> **[sun‧ny](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/sunny)** /ˈsʌni/ ●●● S3 adjective
>
> 1 having a lot of light from the sun SYN bright
>
> a warm sunny day
>
> a sunny morning
>
> a nice sunny room
>
> I hope it’s sunny tomorrow.
>
> sunny periods/spells/intervals (=periods when it is sunny)
>
> Tuesday will be dry with sunny spells.

---

Ok, let say, we look out through the window, and it has some light from the sun but not a lot. In that situation, do we say

"**it is sunny now**" or "**it has sun light now**"?

In the case that it has a lot of sun light outside. Do we say

"**it is sunny now**" or "**it has a lot of sun light now**"?

Finally, Are “**It is rainy now**” and “**it is raining now**” the same? Also what is the verb equivalent to the adjective “**sunny**”?

**Note:** [Some says](https://hinative.com/en-US/questions/925902)

> "It's raining now" is more common, but both "It's raining now" & "It's
>   rainy now" are common and often used.
>
> "It's rainy outside now." works, but "It's raining outside now."
>   works, too.
>
> Although, most agree that "**rainy**" often stands before nouns such
>   as a rainy day, a rainy season, etc

Comment: “Is the sun ***shining*** now?” It's very rare to use "sun" as a verb when we talk about the weather but nothing is impossible nowadays.

Comment: @Mari-LouA, is “Is the sun shining now?” the same as "is it sunny now?"

Comment: Yes, they have both the same meaning. Why do you think the two situations are different?

Comment: @Mari-LouA, because it seems "is it rainy now?" & "is it raining now?" are not the same. Why is that?

Comment: But using "now" tells us the weather is sunny=pleasant at the time of speaking. The dictionary's example `It had been raining hard all night` tells us that it consistently rained all night i.e. "a lot".

Comment: @Mari-LouA, but "It had been raining hard all night" = "It's been rainy all day today.". The dictionary doesn't say "It had been raining hard all night" = "it is rainy now". I don't understand why "it is rainy now" is not the same as "it is raining now" http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/rainy

Comment: You initially asked me: `is “Is the sun shining now?” the same as "is it sunny now?"` I said it was. You also asked in the original post if "raining" meant a lot of rain was falling, by itself it doesn't. It can do if we are looking at it while we speak. To say that a lot of rain is falling we can use "hard" or "a lot" e.g. "It's raining hard / a lot (now)"

Answer (score 3):

Your definition of *rainy* means 'a period when there are frequent showers' (*a lot* doesn't refer to heavy rain). So if rain is falling now we say "It is raining".

There is normally 'some light from the sun' in the daytime. *A sunny day* is when the sun is strong and there are few clouds in the sky. "It has sunlight" is not idiomatic English.
We can say "The sun is shining", which is the only verbal equivalent to "It is raining".

Comment: but can we say "it is sunny"? "If it's sunny later, we can go to the park." http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/sunny

Comment: Certainly we can.

Comment: the dictionary doesn't say "rainy" refers to a period. "Rainy" means "having or bringing a lot of rain". I updated the question.

Comment: I quote from above: **a rainy period of time is one when it rains a lot** , which you had interpreted as 'when it is raining heavily'. A rainy day or rainy season is one in which it rains _frequently_, but not necessarily _all the time_.